# How to detect cyclic dependencies in compile time, in java spring-boot, in eclipse?

Tags: java, spring-boot, eclipse, circular-dependency

Is there any way we can detect cyclic dependencies before running the application?

I'm using eclipse IDE for a spring-boot project. For some reason I can not run my application on my local machine, I need to run it on an external server.

Whenever any cyclic dependency arrives in code, my maven build gets succeeds, so I get to know about that cyclic dependency only on the server which takes the entire server down which is not affordable.

Please suggest a way to detect these evils before they born.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

This is something the Spotbugs plugin can find.  I haven't run it in a while, and I don't remember where it's found in the results, but I've used this to discover these, and not just to tell me that there is one, but it shows the trace of references.

Comment: Thanks David, I'll Check it, and I'll update if it works